# enable caching for all SSRS reports in batch and not one by one

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have more than 40 SSRS reports that i want to add the caching option to it.
The problem is that currently, i enable this option on each report, one by one.
is there a way that i can build a batch of reports that i can enable the caching on them?

thanks in advance,
Eddie

Comment: Eddy, look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772171/enable-caching-for-all-reports-in-ssrs-report-server